# Ruby dbi select statement returning BigDecimal?

Tags: sql, ruby, oracle, dbi

I'm having trouble using ruby with dbi for some reason, I'm trying to do a select and put the results in an array but no luck.

```
require 'dbi'

db = DBI.connect('DBI:OCI8:database', XXXX, XXXX)

#Gets Consumer Id Number you want to create accounts for
numberOfAccounts = []
puts("Please enter a CID")
NewCID = gets.chomp()
numberOfAccounts << db.execute("select T_NBR from T_CBA where C_ID='#{NewCID}'").fetch
```

My array ends up like this:

```
[[<#BigDecimal:fc115f8,'0.8000169202 2E11',12(16)>]]
```

where I would like to have several different numbers like [222, 3232, 2323] etc.

I've searched online but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBI has probably determined that the underlying column can contain integers too large to fit in a regular int type, based on the data field.  Or it may just use BigDecimal for all integer types to avoid worrying about it.

If you know that your values are all small enough to fit into a regular integer, you can convert the array to integers after you've populated it, like so:

```
1.9.3-p194 :014 > numberOfAccounts
=> [[#<BigDecimal:119cd90,'0.123E3',9(36)>], [#<BigDecimal:119cd18,'0.456E3',9(36)>]] 
1.9.3-p194 :015 > numberOfAccounts.flatten!.collect!(&:to_i)
=> [123, 456] 
1.9.3-p194 :016 > numberOfAccounts
=> [123, 456]
```

Comment: On a side note, I was expecting more than one result, how do I get all the results instead of one?

Comment: I was a little confused about whether you wanted an array of arrays (which is how numberOfAccounts was being built) or a single flattened array (which is what you had as your example desired data).  If you still want an array-of-arrays, you can do this: `numberOfAccounts.collect {|row| row.collect(&:to_i)}`, which will yield something like `[[123],[456]]`.

Comment: I was also a little confused with my problem and also frustrated so it is no surprise that I left other people confused!  I actually wanted one singe flattened array, and was expecting to get say the '123' out put instead of the `[#<BigDecimal:119cd90,'0.123E3',9(36)>]`. So I was confused from the start, I didn't realize the number I wanted was being found, you straighten me out and now I'm good Thanks!  p.s found answer to my comment need to use .fetch_all verse .fetch to get all data I want.